# Skype conversation with blank content

Tags: lync, skype-for-business

Our group are using skype for business 2016. I use Microsoft.Lync.Model to start  a conversation to send message, sometimes some people in that conversation can receive the message some of them only show a notification window with no content, this situation appears most if I add more than 2 contact in the conversation. 
and here is the code:

```
    using Microsoft.Lync.Model;
    private void CreateNewConversation(string userinput,List<string> receivers)
    {
        Conversation lyncConversation = lyncClient.ConversationManager.AddConversation();

        foreach (string receiver in receivers)
        {
            Contact contact = lyncClient.ContactManager.GetContactByUri(receiver);

            lyncConversation.AddParticipant(contact);
        }
        InstantMessageModality m = (InstantMessageModality)lyncConversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.InstantMessage];
        m.BeginSendMessage(userinput, null, null);
    }
```

Is something wrong with my code or that API has bugs, or skype for business didn't support that API very well?